# remove only decimal place and not comma

Tags: decimal, rounding

Please i have 123,788.98, I want to remove the decimal place before storing in dbase so as to have just 123,789.
I tried round(123,789.98) but it gives me just 123.

Please how can remove the decimal place without removing the comma?

Comment: Does this work?  REGEXP_REPLACE( '123,788.98', '[.]*', '' )

Answer (score 0):

Divided with comma, these are two numbers. 123 and 788.98. So just round(788.98) and insert them both in one row.

```
INSERT INTO table(row) VALUES ('123,'.round(788.98).'')
```

If you have a comma, you can create two variables from the form input:

```
list($one, $two) = explode(",", "S_POST['amount']", 2);
```

Comment: The thing is that am fetching the value from a form field POST more like round(S_POST['amount']);